# What's the title of this Disney comic about an emerald iceberg?

Tags: story-identification, comics, disney

I'm looking for a Disney comic, in which the characters (pretty sure it's about Uncle $crooge and his nephews, but it could also be Mickey Mouse), go after an Iceberg which becomes green when the sunlight go through it. Those who found it think it must contain a gigantic emerald, and everyone starts looking for it.

> At the end of the story, other icebergs of other colors are found, and there are no gemstones in them, but enormous round bottles of exquisite syrups, which a ship had to throw in the ocean to avoid sinking.

I read it about 15-20 years ago, in French.

Does anyone know the title of this comic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a two-part story titled [*"Indiana Pipps e l'iceberg di smeraldo"*](https://inducks.org/story.php?c=I+TL+2023-4P) (story by Caterina Mognato, drawing by Giuseppe Dalla Santa) published on the Italian Mickey Mouse weekly comic in 1994 and later reprinted and translated in other languages.
In particular, the linked I.N.D.U.C.K.S. page states that there is a French translation (*"Indiana Ding et le trésor de l'iceberg"*) dated 1997.

[image: Title panel of the first part]

The story features **Indiana Pipps** (aka Arizona Goof, a cousin of Goofy's clearly modeled after Indiana Jones) and **Mickey Mouse** trying to locate a legendary iceberg containing a huge emerald. The evil **Doctor Kranz** is on their tracks and will do anything to put his hands on the fabled gem.

I couldn't find a more detailed synopsis, so I don't know if the story ends with the twist you remember.